# ¿Cómo obtener las propiedades de las tablas de una clave en un diccionario?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un archivo json y me gustaria obtener filtrarlo en json para obtener cada de los `id_4`.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ],
              ...
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.27286911,
          33.22112656,
          -6.93353081,
          33.38970184
        ],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {
          "PI": 187,
          "PJD": 88,
          "PAM": 59,
          "USFP": 1530,
          "APFGD": 2,
          "PPS": 15,
          "RNI": 708,
          "MP": 56,
          "UC": 3,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 8,
          "PEDD": 0,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 0,
          "USAPMD": 10
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 5953,
          "nbre_votants": 2997,
          "nbre_nuls": 328,
          "nbre_exprimees": 2669
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    },
    ...
```

Lo hicé en python pero me gustaria hacerlo en javascript:

```
with open('data/Morocco/maroc-swing.json') as f:
    dct = json.load(f)
constituencies = [dct['features'][i]['properties']['name_4'] for i in range(0,len(dct['features']))]
```

Intenté:

```
> var fs = require('fs');
undefinedo Node.js v12.14.1.
> var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('maroc-swing.json'));
undefined
> keys.forEach(key => {
... console.log(obj[key]);
... });
Thrown:
ReferenceError: keys is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que la variable `keys` no existe.

Al igual que lo hiciste en `Python`, los que necesitas es iterar la propiedad `obj.features`, así por ejemplo:

```js
let json = `{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": []
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {},
        "voter_file": {},
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    }]}`;
    
let obj = JSON.parse(json);
let constituencies = obj.features.map((f) => f.properties.id_4);
console.log(constituencies);
```

***PD**: Borre contenido del `JSON` ya que era irrelevante para la solución. Esto no afecta a la solución.*